# convertir entero en array. si tengo un array y yo quiero que el primer numero sea un array de por si

Tags: java, array

si tengo por ejemplo:

```
int arr[]= {0101,0110,0111,1010,1011,1101,1110,1111}
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     int arr1=arr[i]; 
}
```

y yo quiero que ese arr1 sea por si otro arry.

> que me quede {0,1,0,1}
> para asi poder preguntar por cada numero por seprado.

Comment: Solo para aclarar... 0101 es un número octal y no binario, estás consciente de ello? Querías que fuera binario? (en tu arreglo están mezclados octales y decimales)

Comment: no estoy utilizando ese número como uno binario si no como cualquier número entero de cuatro dígitos.

Comment: entonces por que poner 0111 y no 73?

Comment: porque así fue el ejercicio que me mandaron... pero ok, digamos que es 73 o cualquier número entero que no sea binario, como lo paso a un array, o sea que me quede {7,3} ?